# Django: Serializer automatically parse json field and add to common fields

Tags: json, django, serialization

I call serializer:

`serializer = MySerializer(qs, many=True)` when `qs` - QuerySets for myModel

```
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
class MySerializer(Serializer):

   param1 = CharField()
   param2 = IntegerField(required=False)
   custom_fields = JSONField()

   class Meta:
        pass
```

Next, I just use the `custom_fields` and get the values manually.
Is it possible at this stage to get the fields inside this `custom_fields` and return them through the serializer?

`custom_fields` contains:

```
{
 'custom_value1': 3, 
 'custom_value2': 5
}
```

`updated`: What i want to get after serializer:

```
{
 'param1': 'value1',
 'param2': 'value2',
 'custom_value1': 3, 
 'custom_value2': 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I exactly understand your question... You're asking that you can GET your custom field's data?

Then answer is **Yes**

If you just call GET request to APIView using `MySerializer`, you can get all data from your model.

If you want to get data from your Model, you simply using `ModelSerializer`. (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer). `ModelSerializer` is much easier but you can use your own serializer, too.

Nowadays I experienced similar situation, and I can get all my extra data (same as you, it's json object)

I attach my serializer and respone. I hope it helps you.

**My serialzier** (`extra` field is `JsonField`)

```
class JobUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobUser
        fields = (
            "email",
            "is_active",
            "is_staff",
            "id",
            "extra",
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            "id",
        )
```

**My response** (GET request to viewsets. You can see extra json data)

```
{
    "email": "test5@test.com",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "id": 13,
    "extra": {
        "last_name": "kim",
        "first_name": "seul",
        "gcf_spouses_name": "test",
        "gcf_spouses_position": "test"
    }
},
```

### Update

I think you can use `get_*` method and use it.

this is example code for mine

```
class JobUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name_from_extra = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = JobUser
        fields = (
            "email",
            "is_active",
            "is_staff",
            "id",
            # "extra",
            "first_name_from_extra"
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            "id",
        )

    def get_first_name_from_extra(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.extra['first_name']
        except TypeError:
            return ""
```

Then you can access directly "first_name" (my extra json field's key)

**My response**

```
{
    "email": "test5@test.com",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "id": 13,
    "first_name_from_extra": "seul"
},
```

> Be careful using this method: your json field SHOULD have that key. If one of your serializing model don't have the key, it raises `NoneType TypeError`. Or you can use `try/except` in `get_*` method.

Hope helping!

Comment: Sorry, I added the changes to my question. Right now I'm doing the same as you.
But I wanted to have these fields without a parent

Comment: Oh I thought wrong. I will update my answer to that direction.

Comment: Another small question - if we do not know which fields are in extra, then it seems we can not parse it, no way to return like i want?

Comment: Well, maybe it can.. I think I have to try some in serializers. I guess it's possible by iterating all 'extra' key and gives it to serializers. After trying, I will update my answer.